# array_push pushes to many items in my session array PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I'm creating a litle webshop for fun. Each time a user clicks on a cetrain button, the function `addToChart()` is called. In this function i push all the needed data into an array. Afterward I send this array to a php script (addToCart.php) using AJAX POST method as you can see in my javascript code bellow:

```
function addToChart(deze) {
    const brandContainer = deze.parentNode;
    const productName = brandContainer.children[0].innerHTML;

    addToCartProductArr.push(productName);

    $.ajax({
        url: "./*/addToCart.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {arr:addToCartProductArr},
    });
}
```

In the `addToCart.php` I fetch the passed array and store it into `$arr` variable. Afterwards i'm looping over this array and push all the data (with `array_push()` method), into a session array because i need to work with this session array in other php script.

```
<?php
include_once('./conn.php');
session_start();

$arr = $_POST['arr'];

if(!isset($_SESSION['name_arr'])) {
    $_SESSION['name_arr'] = array();
}

for($i=0; $i<sizeof($arr); $i++) {
    array_push($_SESSION['name_arr'], $arr[$i]);
}

?>
```

PROBLEM: When a user clicks on the button, the data is stored multiple times into the session array. For example: Hitting 3 times an item gives me 5 items in my session_array for example:

When i print_r the session array: [image: print_r of session array]

HTML CODE:

```
<p onclick="addToChart(this)" class="addToChart"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></p>
```

Comment: The HTML code for the button is missing from your question. My guess would be that this button has multiple event handlers associated with it.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I posted the HTML code

Comment: Well, that only seems to have one event. You could still check this with the programmers tools of your browser. Check how often, when, and with what parameters `addToCart.php` is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your original php is correct just make script like this in the javascript

```
function addToChart(deze) {
var addToCartProductArr=[];
const brandContainer = deze.parentNode;
const productName = brandContainer.children[0].innerHTML;

addToCartProductArr.push(productName);

$.ajax({
url: "addToCart.php",
method: "POST",
data: {arr:addToCartProductArr},

});
}
```

What we just do is that we init the array every time the function is called by :

```
 var addToCartProductArr=[];
```

Comment: yes , just try this : if (!in_array($arr[$i], $_SESSION['name_arr'])){array_push($_SESSION['name_arr'], $arr[$i]);}

Comment: What if someone really wants to add the same product multiple times?

Comment: @AlaaKaddour I understand what you mean but, a specific element can be added multiple times. If i hit the first button twice for example (first element), it will add it only once the the session array. Can I increse a counter to keep the amount of products added or something like that?

Comment: if i understand ,you wanna insert name once and the other many times as he clicks the button ,right ?

Comment: @AlaaKaddour So a user can add each product as many as he want so for example a first product can be added 3 times, second product 4 times, etc.. If i use the code you wrote, a specific product can only be stored once in the array

Comment: so to do that ,i suggest that you insert the first [0] the username or the name of user after that you insert the product every time to do that, we should pass to the php only the product name in array ,and a seperate var with the name of client . i give you the code .

Comment: Thanks a lot i'm waiting for it!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223556/discussion-between-darkfelcore-and-alaa-kaddour).